# Different ordering in multiple indexes on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a table with a clustered index defined:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX dbo.T_IX_TimeStamp ON dbo.T (TimeStamp DESC)
```

I also need to have an unique index for fast retrieval by a key (so ordering is not important):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED UNIQUE INDEX dbo.T_IX_EntryId ON dbo.T (EntryId)
```

Will I or DB engine somehow benefit if I also make `T_IX_EntryId` ordered **DESC** in terms of performance?

Comment: It should make no difference whatsoever.  The two indexes are not related to each other.

Comment: Index sort order makes very little/no performance difference when there is only one column in the index. If you are indexing multiple fields and will often query for most recent records, then sort order can have impact.

Comment: I would note that creating a clustered index on a descending timestamp seems like a bad idea.  When you add new records with a more recent timestamp, it will need to add them to the beginning of the table, which will result in a lot of page splits as the existing data gets "pushed back" to make room for the insert.  Selects may be faster, but I'd bet you'd see poor performance on inserts (if that is a concern).

Comment: @DStanley, are you the engine doesn't store records from the bottom to the top of the page? That would be silly not to do.

Comment: Why would it be silly?  It depends on the engine but the "natural" thing to do would be to store records in the order that they are added.  Most engines that I know of are optimized to store data this way - append to the end.  Having a clustered index that stores records differently forces reorganizations that hurt insert performance.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no benefit to having different indexes sort in the same direction.  Once the non-clustered index is used, it uses the individual pointers of each index row to get to the actual data row.  So the direction has no effect.